# Formal Proof: P(A∩B'∩C') = P(A) - P(A∩B) - P(A∩C) + P(A∩B∩C)

Tags: probability-theory, proof-writing

I'm trying to prove the following:

$\newcommand{\P}{\operatorname{\bf P}}\P(A\cap \overline{B}\cap\overline{C}) = \P(A) - \P(A\cap B) - \P(A\cap C) + \P(A\cap B\cap C)$

I can explain it with a venn diagram, but I'm so not familiar with formal proofs. I know of De Morgan’s Rules, i.e. $\overline{B}\cap\overline{C} = (\overline{A\cup B})$, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: What are the three axioms of probability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\begin{align}\newcommand{\P}{\operatorname{\bf P}}\P(A\cap \overline{B}\cap\overline{C}) & = \P(A) - \P(A\cap B) - \P(A\cap C) + \P(A\cap B\cap C)
\\[2ex] \text{Use:} &\quad\text{the Law of Total Probability}
\\[1ex] \P(X) & = \P(X\cap\bar Y) + \P(X\cap Y)
\\\therefore \P(X\cap\bar Y) & = \P(X) - \P(X\cap Y)
\end{align}$

Comment: Thanks. I think I know how to do it now. P(A)P(C)=P(A∩C), right?

Comment: @user169404 Not necessarily.  There's no guarantee of independence. All you need is to apply the LoTP once, then apply it to each of the resulting terms.  **Hint:** for the first step, think $X=A\cap\bar B$ and $Y=\bar C$.

Answer (score 0):

$P(A \cap B' \cap C')=P(A \cap B' \cap C')+P(A \cap B' \cap C)- P(A \cap B' \cap C)=P(A \cap B')-P(A \cap B' \cap C)=P(A \cap B')+P(A \cap B)-P(A \cap B)- P(A \cap B' \cap C)=P(A)-P(A \cap B)- P(A \cap B' \cap C)$.

Now manipulate $P(A \cap B' \cap C )$ in a similar fashion to get $P(A \cap B \cap C)-P(A \cap C)$. (Hint:$P(A \cap B' \cap C )+P(A \cap C)=P(A \cap B \cap C)$ )